# Does this proof work for infinite regular languages

Tags: formal-languages, regular-languages, closure-properties

My proof was deemed false because it does not work for infinite regular languages, but I don't understand why.

Prove: "If we remove one string from any nonempty regular set, the resulting set is still regular.

I used to lemmas:

- A set containing only one string is trivially a regular language
- The union operator is closed in the class of regular languages

Given these two lemmas, I made the claim that any regular language $L$ can be written in the form
$$L = \bigcup_{e \in L}\{e\}$$

Then, one picks an arbitrary string $r \in L$ to remove, and expresses $L$ in the same manner with $r$ distinct:
$$L = \bigcup_{e \in (L - \{r\})}\{e\} \cup \{r\}, \quad r \in L$$

Finally, we simply remove $r$ from the union and obtain:
$$L' = \bigcup_{e \in (L - \{r\})}\{e\}$$

$L'$ is also regular by the two lemmas introduced earlier.

Comment: You implicitly use the proposition "if A and B are regular languages, and $A=B\cup C$, then C is a regular language". This is different from the proposition "the union operator is closed in the class of regular languages".

Comment: "My proof was deemed false because it does not work for infinite regular languages" -- this doesn't seem to be helpful critique. Your proof does not work at all; it has nothing to do with whether $L$ is finite.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with your argument is in the interpretation of the second lemma. Closure under union says "If $L_1$ and $L_2$ are regular languages, then $L_1\cup L_2$ is regular." By induction, then, the union of any *finite* collection of regular languages is regular. You cannot, however, conclude that the union of an arbitrary collection of regular languages is regular, as Raphael pointed out, since your observation
$$
L=\bigcup_{e\,\in\, L}\{e\}
$$
is true for *any* language at all, regular or not, so since a single string language is regular, then *every* language would be regular.

---

What you could do is exploit some other closure properties of regular languages. For instance

1. If $L_1$ and $L_2$ are regular languages, so is $L_1\cap L_2$.
2. If $L$ is a regular language, its complement $\overline{L}$ is too.
3. We can thus write the set difference $A\setminus B$ as $A\cap\overline{B}$ so regular languages are closed under set difference.
4. If $L$ is any regular language and $e\in L$ is any string in $L$, then $L\setminus \{e\}$ must also be regular.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you don't actually *show* anything.

*Every* language can be expressed as union of singletons. So being able to write down $L'$ as such does not show it's regular. For all we know, it may not even be recursively enumerable.